# How to repair synthetic nylon pouch

Tags: clothing, repair

I've got a zipper pouch made of synthetic material (it feels like nylon but I'm not entirely certain) which is partly made of a loose "mesh" weave:

[image: Synthetic pouch with tears in mesh highlighted]

As you can see in the photo above, this loose mesh has been torn:

[image: Close-up of biggest tear]

How can I best repair this so that the integrity of the pouch is restored?-- Of course, the main point is so that smaller things don't fall out of the pouch through the tear(s) and that the repaired spots are strong enough to enable the pouch to hold heavy items without re-tearing.

### Previous attempts

I haven't done anything to try to fix it yet because I have no idea how to fix it --- hence posting this question online.

### Skills

I am terrible at sewing but can do it, and am also willing to learn new skills in order to fix the pouch --- hence posting this question online.

Comment: O unseen downvoter, care to explain your mysterious ways?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but there are guidelines we like to know before answering a question: What have you tried so far? Why did it not work for you? How is replacing the fabric not going to work? Are you capable of sewing?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman: I didn't write anything because I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Have you thought about buying similar material and taking it to someone who can sew? Maybe even someone professional? Like a seamstress or clothing repair.

Comment: Yes, I've looked into it but **a)** the pouch was bought in the US about 15 years ago and I currently live in a country where even material is literally several times the price of what the entire pouch was back then and **b)** I thought an SE called "[Lifehacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_hacking)" would encourage a "[DIY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_it_yourself)" attitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is two ways you can fix this.

1) Cut a piece of material slightly bigger than the hole in the mesh and stick it with a strong glue... i.e. open the pocket, put your hand in it with a piece of wood with the material being on the wood. With your other hand, take another piece of flat wood and push them together. Hopefully that does the job as the material should prevent future rips in the materials.

2) Sewing... try to sow the rips together, pulling the thread through the opposite sides of the rip, going all the way around. The problem with this is that you will end up with a thick line (one you complete the fix), but it will do the job if done correctly.

Either way, this is a hard fix as you will be able to see were the rip has happened in the past.

Comment: Sewing the edges together should work, as it is a tear and no fabric is actually missing. Use polyester thread not cotton. If you can, use thicker thread (like for buttonholes), or use ordinary sewing thread doubled. Yes, the repair will be visible. If you can't sew, or don't possess a needle, ask someone else to do it, maybe in return for doing a small job for them?